# Single endpoint with multiple service contracts

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-endpoint, servicecontract

How can I write a WCF web service that has single endpoint but multiple service contract?

Example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWirelessService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddWireless();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IWiredService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddWired();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IInternetService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddInternet();
}
```

Lets think like IInternetService is my main webs service and i want to implement IwiredService and IWirelessService in it, but i want to do implementation in their classes.Is this possible? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you see this question? I think it has the answer for what you are trying to do... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334472/run-wcf-servicehost-with-multiple-contracts)

Comment: Thanks, that is actually what i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have given the below example is it what you were looking for?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWirelessService : IInternetService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Connection AddInternet();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IWiredService : IInternetService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Connection AddInternet();
}

public class WirelessService : IWirelessService 
{
   public Connection AddInternet()
   {
   //Get Internet the wireless way
   }

}

public class WiredService : IWiredService 
{
    public Connection AddInternet()
    {
    //Get Internet the wired way
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IInternetService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Connection AddInternet();
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IEnterpriseApplicationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void GetDataFromInternet(string url, IInternetService internetService);
}
public class InternetProviderService : IEnterpriseApplicationService
{ 
    public HTMLResponse GetDataFromInternet(string url, IInternetService internetService)
    {
       Connection con = internetService.AddInternet();
       return con.GetContentFromURL(url);
    }
 }
```

Comment: From the "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334472/run-wcf-servicehost-with-multiple-contracts" link i get the solution.Actually partial classes help me.Thanks for help.