# WCF multiple services same contract in same Config

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Im trying to host to different service implementations of the same contract:

[image: Model]

The reason is that need a dummy implementation for out-of-the-house testing.

Im trying to host both in the same WindowsService:

```
    private ServiceHost _host;
    private ServiceHost _dummy;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
        _host.Open();

 //trying to avoid the app.config beeing used - because its already been hoste by _host
        _dummy = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestDummyService));
        _dummy.Description.Endpoints.Clear();
        _dummy.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), 
                                   new WebHttpBinding(),
                                  @"<link>/Dummy.svc/");
        _dummy.ChannelDispatchers.Clear();
        _dummy.Open();
     }
```

This is the config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="namespace.Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="<link>/Service.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="namespace.IService" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="web" />

        <endpoint address="/mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors >
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                           httpGetUrl="<link>/Service.svc/About" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="web">
          <webHttp />         
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The ChannelDispatcher at /Service.svc/About with Contracts ‘IHttpGetHelpPageAndMetadataContract’ is unable to open.

any help is appreciated.

Update 1
My goal is to have 2 different implementations of the same contract (`IService`) hosted in one WindowsService.

I would also like to configure both of them in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found out, that even thow the testdummy service was added programatic, it still got the service metadatabehavior.

My solution was to not make the dehavior default - given it at name:

app.config:

```
<service name="namespace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="someName">
```

//.. later:

```
    <behavior name="someName">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                       httpGetUrl="<link>/Service.svc/About" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
```

The rest of the code, statyed the same

Answer (score 1):

Well i would like to know what's the business scenario. All I guess is, the client should not know the implementation, its just the URL of the service would indicate (or route) to the implementation.

Kindly clarify.

---

Refer to this existing [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567810/single-endpoint-with-multiple-service-contracts) and let
 me know if it makes sense.

---

The above post is hinting the implementation, refer to this [post](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/multiple-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) for deployment details.

Comment: The link have it vice versa. I only have one contract, but multiple implementations of that contract. also the link didn't provide any information on how to host the darn thing :) But thanks for feedback

Comment: Well in the above post, there is only 1 Contract and 2 implementations, am not sure why it did not helped you. I have edited the answer and added one more link. Hope it helps...

Comment: I'll give you one for trying, but the link is not what i was looking for. sry

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add another endpoint and fill in the adress with a distinct name:

```
<endpoint address="/SecondService" 
              binding="webHttpBinding2" 
              contract="namespace.IService" 
               />
```

Url becomes /Service.svc/SecondService

Comment: hi - thnks for the feedback. No unfortnally i can't. because the endpoint don't let me decide what implementation i uses. that is specified in the service tag: `<service name ="namespace.ImplementationClassName">`