# WCF - have more than one .svc service in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, jquery, wcf-binding

I have created in Visual Studio 2010 a C#/ASP.NET application, and in that a `service.svc` file and the corresponding

- `IService.cs` //Contract
- `Service.cs` //Implementation of the contract - interface

and this WCF service returns my data in JSON. I hit it with jQuery ajax post. This service seemed to work as I wanted it but then I decided to add a second service i.e. `ServiceNew.svc` with its corresponding

- `IServiceNew.cs` //Contract
- `ServiceNew.cs` //Implementation of the contract - interface

and adding the corresponding endpoint in the `web.config`.

After I added the second WCF service then none of the services worked it returned an 500 internal server error.

The most weird part is that if I remove from the folder of my application all the new files `ServiceNew.svc`, `IServiceNew.cs`, `ServiceNew.cs` the first `Service.svc` works when I hit them with jQuery posts as before, and then if I simply copy these files back again to my folder and run the Visual Studio host then BOTH of my services (old AND new) work for a random period of time and then they again suddenly return 500 error when I hit them with a jQuery ajax call.

My `web.config` is:

```
<system.serviceModel>       
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
         <webHttp/>
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
       <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
     </service>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServiceNew">
       <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="IServiceNew" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

`IService.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "d")]
    MovieInfo GetMovieInfo(string title, string year);
}
```

`Service.cs`:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
    = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service: IService
{
    public MovieInfo GetMovieInfo(string title, string year)
    {
          ...
          return MovieInfo();
        }
}
```

Similarly

`IServiceNew.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceNew
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "d")]
    string GetConf();
}
```

`ServiceNew.cs`:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
    = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ServiceNew: IServiceNew
{
    public string GetConf()
    {
          ...
          return conf;
        }
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? How I can add more than one WCF services ( .svc files) in a ASP.NET application, in order to hit them with jQuery ajax calls?

Is something wrong with my `web.config`?

Is it something else?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

As an update I can say that when I try to Debug one of the .svc files, let's say the ServiceNew.svc in the browser the below exception is displayed:

Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_oq2tdtg4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_oq2tdtg4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +210
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1461
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +651

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/ServiceNew.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_oq2tdtg4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +687598
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService) +234
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +24
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Assembly Load Trace:

The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'App_Web_oq2tdtg4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ZULUTRADE\stassis
LOG: DisplayName = App_Web_oq2tdtg4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/stassis/Documents/Development/theDreamBox/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\stassis\Documents\Development\theDreamBox\bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\stassis\Documents\Development\theDreamBox\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/87ef3319/ec80b2f5/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/87ef3319/ec80b2f5/App_Web_oq2tdtg4/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/Documents/Development/theDreamBox/bin/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/Documents/Development/theDreamBox/bin/App_Web_oq2tdtg4/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/87ef3319/ec80b2f5/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/87ef3319/ec80b2f5/App_Web_oq2tdtg4/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/Documents/Development/theDreamBox/bin/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/stassis/Documents/Development/theDreamBox/bin/App_Web_oq2tdtg4/App_Web_oq2tdtg4.EXE.

Comment: can you check that wsdl files are publishing properly when you try to call them using a web browser?

Comment: Are you running it on your developent machine? Does the event log give you more information? And how big is the dataset you are returning from the services?

Comment: Yes I am running it on my development machine. I will update my post and also write the logs that I think you want. This logs are mentioned in the exception and on what it is shown in the browser when I run in debug mode my ServiceNew.svc file

Comment: Sorry, but I cant spot the error, so I'll keep asking questions: What settings for Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies do you use? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I´m not quite sure but you bind both services to same address, probably you have change the endpoint address for each service-implementation

```
<services>
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
   <endpoint address="a" binding="webHttpBinding"
       contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
 </service>
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServiceNew">
   <endpoint address="b" binding="webHttpBinding"
       contract="IServiceNew" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
 </service>
```

Comment: I have tried what you just said with the addresses but again it throws the same error
and the same exception is thrown when running the ServiceNew.svc in Debug (F5)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug which results in similar behavior of you are observing. I do not know whether this is the exact issue but you may check [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915782/en-us).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my service a few days back [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771686/wcf-multiple-services-same-contract-in-same-config)

The problem was that I could not have to services implementations int one .config file.

When I hosted the service I had to give the `ServiceHost` a type of the implementation - but since tow was defined in the config file it keep throwing an error.

My solution was to add one service from the config, and add the other (to a different `ServiceHost`) in C#