# how to host 2 wcf services in 1 servicehost

Tags: wcf, service, host

i'm working on a wcf project
i have 1 service with 2 contracts (2 endpoints)
and 1 service with 1 contract (1 endpoint)
i want to make 1 single ServiceHost for both my services.
i can make 2 host for 2 services but i need only 1 host.

```
ServiceHost myService =
            new ServiceHost(typeof(CustomerOrder),
            new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9191/T1Flondor_Antal"));

            ServiceHost myService2 =
            new ServiceHost(typeof(ReportServiceCO),
            new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9191/T1Flondor_Antal"));
```

and the config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="T1Flondor_Antal.CustomerOrder"
     behaviorConfiguration="T1Flondor_Antal.MessageBehavior">
        <endpoint address ="net.tcp://localhost:9191/T1Flondor_Antal/Customer"
       binding="netTcpBinding"
       contract="T1Flondor_Antal.ICustomer">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address ="net.tcp://localhost:9191/T1Flondor_Antal/Order"
       binding="netTcpBinding"
       contract="T1Flondor_Antal.IOrder">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
       binding="mexTcpBinding"
       contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>


      <service name="T1Flondor_Antal.ReportServiceCO"
     behaviorConfiguration="T1Flondor_Antal.MessageBehavior">
        <endpoint address ="net.tcp://localhost:9191/T1Flondor_Antal/Report"
       binding="netTcpBinding"
       contract="T1Flondor_Antal.IReport">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>   
        <endpoint address="mex"
       binding="mexTcpBinding"
       contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>



    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="T1Flondor_Antal.MessageBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: 1 `ServiceHost` can host exactly **one** service implementation class; but that service implementation could potentially implement more than one service contract (interface)....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run WCF ServiceHost with multiple contracts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334472/run-wcf-servicehost-with-multiple-contracts)

Answer (score 2):

See [Run WCF ServiceHost with multiple contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334472/run-wcf-servicehost-with-multiple-contracts) :

You need to implement both interfaces in a single object and use that object when constructing your ServiceHost.

Otherwise: No, you can't do that.